# Procedure performance slows when used sp parameters in where condition

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure which executes in 4 seconds if used hard coded values like ''='' in where condition as shown below:

```
alter procedure proc1
( @filter varchar(400)=null )
as
begin 
select a,b,c from tbl1 where ''=''
end
```

but when I pass it as stored procedure parameter as shown below:

```
alter procedure proc1
( @filter varchar(400)=null )
as
begin
select a,b,c from tbl1 where @filter=''
end`
```

it takes approximately 7 to 8 minutes when I call it from my application
or directly execute it using execute statement in SQL Server

```
exec proc1 ''
```

Above given sp is just an example. The procedure actually is big consists of many select statements and user defined functions but the issue occurs in the similar statement as given above.

Where condition:

```
  where 
et.X is not null and et.Y is not null and e.EquipmentName is not null AND e.Available='Available'

--and (Select dbo.GetFilterStatusOfEquipment(getdate(),'70','50','ON'))='*'
AND (
(dbo.GetFilterStatusOfEquipment(et.SignalDateTime,et.SpeedOfTheVehicle,(SELECT COUNT(J.JobId) FROM tbl_Notification J 
               inner JOIN tbl_NotificationAssign JN ON  JN.NotificationNo =J.NotificationNo
               inner JOIN dbo.tbl_CustomStatus JS ON JS.CustomStatusID=J.CustomStatusID 
               INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_SystemStatus ss ON ss.SystemStatusID=JS.SystemStatusID
               WHERE JN.DriverID=et.DriverID AND ss.SystemStatusID !=9),et.IgnitionStatus) 
              in (Select val from Split(@filter,',')) or (@filter='')))

and (et.CompanyID=@CompanyID or @CompanyID='') AND e.Flag_Delete='0'
```

GetFilterStatusOfEquipment and Split are UDF.

" or (@filter='') " slows down the query, but if I write ''='' directly into query and execute, it runs fine.

Comment: I sniff PARAMETER SNIFFING...

http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html

Comment: if its parameter sniffing how to solve it? I cant change the way of calling my sp. I have also checked it using dummy variable but still the same results for me.

Comment: (1)option(recompile) and the end of query 
(2)dynamic query ( prone to sql injection)
(3)swap variable in between so optimizer uses avg Rows
(4) using DEfault values OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR)

Comment: I don't understand your first example `select a,b,c from tbl1 where ''=''` - this is not valid SQL, can you elaborate?

Comment: http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/the-elephant-and-the-mouse-or-parameter-sniffing-in-sql-server/

Comment: tried option(recompile) also.but again same results.

Comment: than i request please post Actual query and execution plan if possible

Comment: Isn't writing `WHERE ''=''` the same as writing `WHERE 1=1` and effectively cancels out the WHERE clause, as opposed to using the variable which might necessitate a table scan or something else that might slow the query?

Answer (score 0):

1.Using dummy variables that are not directly displayed on parameters also ensure execution plan stability without need to add recompile hint, example below:

```
alter procedure proc1
( @filter varchar(400) = NULL)
as
begin 
  declare @filterDummy varchar(400)
  set @filterDummy  = @filter

  select a,b,c from tbl1 where @filterDummy = ''
end
```

2.To prevent this and other similar situations, you can use the following query option:

```
OPTIMIZE FOR
RECOMPILE
```

3.Disable auto-update statistics during the batch

Comment: Disable auto-update statistics during the batch why?

Comment: Because at some point in the future the server must compile/recompile a new plan for the stored procedure (the prior plan may have been aged out of cache or auto update statistics kicked in on the Products table, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your query is complicate and SQL Server takes long time to generate the plan.

In that case, i would suggest you to use dynamic query and sp_executesql with the query option KEEPFIXEDPLAN if your statistics are updated automiticaly.

```
Declare @Query nvarchar(max),@QueryParameters nvarchar(max)

Set @Query='select a,b,c from tbl1 where @filter='''' OPTION(KEEPFIXED PLAN)'
Set @QueryParameter='@filter varchar(400)'

sp_executesql @Query,@QueryParameters,@filter=@filter
```

Option KEEPFIXED PLAN is to used only if you have enable automatic update of statistics.

Here is an article about recompiling of store procedure by using KEEPFIXED PLAN option : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/276220

Answer (score 0):

When you use such expression as:
    `in (Select val from Split(@filter,',')) or (@filter=''`)
or 
`et.CompanyID=@CompanyID or @CompanyID=''`
where [CompanyID] column has index or [CompanyID] is a Primary Key, then the execution plan contains index 'scan operator' instead 'index seek' operator.

In this case you should generate query.

For example:

```
alter procedure proc1
( @filter varchar(400)=null )
as
begin
  declare @query nvarchar(1000)
  set @query='select * from tbl'
  if (@filter<>'')
    set @query=@query+' where id in (Select val from split(@filter,'',''))'

  EXECUTE sp_executesql @query ,
  N'@filter nvarchar(30)',
  @filter =@filter
end
```

or use IF statement

```
alter procedure proc1
( @filter varchar(400)=null )
as
begin
  if (@filter<>'')
    select * from tbl 
    where id in (Select val from split(@filter,','))
  else 
    select * from tbl 
end
```